# Process a 1/2 billion rows with PySpark creates shuffle read problems

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

I am apparently facing a read shuffle problems.

My Pyspark Script is running on a Hadoop cluster 1 EdgeNode and 12 Datanodes, using YARN as resources manager and Spark 1.6.2.

```
###[ini_file containing conf spark]
spark.app.name = MY_PYSPARK_APP
spark.master = yarn-client
spark.yarn.queue = agr_queue
spark.executor.instances = 24
spark.executor.memory = 14
spark.executor.cores = 3
#spark.storage.memoryFraction = 0.5
#spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 2001
#spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 1000
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 100
spark.shuffle.memoryFraction=0.5
spark.memory.offHeap.enabled = True
spark.serializer = org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
#spark.driver.memory = 14g
spark.driver.maxResultSize = 20g
spark.python.worker.memory = 14g
spark.akka.heartbeat.interval = 100
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2000
spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=2000
spark.scheduler.mode = FIFO
spark.sql.tungsten.enabled = True
spark.default.parallelism = 200
spark.speculation = True
spark.speculation.interval = 1000ms
spark.speculation.multiplier = 2.0
```

#### Python script

```
sconf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(sconf)
hctx = HiveContext(sc)

dataframe1 = hctx.sql("SELECT * FROM DB1.TABLE1")
dataframe2 = hctx.sql("SELECT * FROM DB2.TABLE2")

df = dataframe1.join(dataframe2, conditions)

# No major problem at this count()
# it returns 550 000 000 rows
df.count()

# 288 elements in List_dtm_t
List_dtm_t=['00:00:00', '00:05:00', ... '23:45:00', '23:50:00', '23:55:00']
dat_tm_bdcst = sc.broadcast(List_dtm)
global dat_tm_bdcst

def mapper(row):
        import datetime
        def ts_minus_5(tmstmp):
            import datetime
            return tmstmp-datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)

        lst_tuple = ()
        poids = row[9]

        for dtm in dat_tm_bdcst.value:
            t_minus = ts_minus_5(dtm)

            if (row[0]<=dtm) & (row[1]>t_minus):

                v1 = str(dtm)
                v2 = str(t_minus)
                v3 = row[2]
                v4 = row[3]
                v5 = row[4]
                v6 = row[5]
                v7 = row[6]
                v8 = row[7]
                v9 = row[8]
                v10 = row[10]
                v11 = poids * (min(dtm,row[1])-max(t_minus,row[0])).total_seconds()
                v12 = poids

                if row[0] <= dtm <= row[1] : v13 = poids
                else : v13 = 0

                lst_tuple += (((v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10),(v11, v12, v13)),)

        return lst_tuple

global list_to_row
def list_to_row(keys, values):
    from pyspark.sql import Row
    row_dict = dict(zip(keys, values[0]+values[1]))
    return Row(**row_dict)

f_reduce = lambda x,y: (x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1], x[2]+y[2])

# This flatMap takes a really infinite long time
# It generally returns a KO because it retries more than 3 times
# Or lose some shuffle path
mapped_df = df.limit(10000000)\
              .flatMap(mapper)

reduced_rdd = mapped_df.reduceByKey(f_reduce)

reduced_rdd.count()

list_of_rows = reduced_rdd.map(lambda x: list_to_row(header, x))

df_to_exp = hctx.createDataFrame(list_of_rows)

## register as tempTable df_to_exp then write it into Hive
```

I tried different ways like :

- Resolve skew problem using repartition([keys]) to distribute data by keys used by the reducer then
- Different values for spark.sql.shuffle.partitions, spark.default.parallelism and memoryOverhead conf
- A partial dataframe version using grouypBy
- Use persistence even if I pass over the data only one time

**I am looking for solution to reach the end and also speed up the process.**

Two screenshot of spark UI:

[List of Stages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BV2ls.png)

[ReduceByKey Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4hbK.png)

We can see the ReduceByKey stage (don't know if it represents only the reduce task, with only 1 task ?!!)
And the shuffle read /records which inscrease too slowly (300 000/100Millions after 13 minutes)

Hope someone could help,
Thanks !